# DTSX and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, bids, ssdt-bi

I am a freelancer. At a client's place, SQL Server is 2014, but the only DTSX tool is BIDS 9, which I would like to remove to install something a bit more up-to-date.
I am a bit confused by some pages telling that SSDT is for VS 2012 or 2013, and that SSDT and SSDT-BI are 2 different things.
So what should I install ? Can I use VS 2015 community + an extra package ?
I would be delighted to have the proper links, because I found MS site is also a bit confusing on the subject, and I would not like to make a mistake on this.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd probably install the latest SSDT bits for VS2015. If you download from the SSDT blog, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/, you can get the latest bits and the IDE as well. You can easily change your target to 2014 and be ready for SSIS 2016 if that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx) has a pretty clear description.

> SSDT contains templates for building relational databases for the RDBMS and Azure SQL Database
>
> SSDT-BI contains project templates for SSAS models, SSRS reports, and
>   SSIS packages.

There are two version of SSDT-BI. One for VS2012 and one for VS2013.

> For SQL Server 2012 or 2014, you can use either SSDT-BI for Visual
>   Studio 2012 or SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013. The only difference is
>   between the two is the Visual Studio version.

You can use the download links on the page to get the right tools for the VS version that one plan on using.